# Cannot see changes in Wordpress in FTP client and vice versa

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I am having some problems with `Wordpress 3.7`. I think they may be related and have something to do with a file ownership/rights issue but I am completely stuck.

- I am using the default theme and I have uploaded a new header image
  several times through the WP admin interface. Now that I am happy
  with the image, I want to delete the old images. Firebug tells me
  they are in `[my wp root]/wp-content/uploads/2014/01`. However, in my
  FTP client, this directory is not visible. I only see `[my wp
  root]/wp-content/uploads/2013`
  .
- When I log into the Wordpress admin interface, it tells me I should upgrade to 3.8. When I tell it to go ahead and give it my FTP credentials, it begins but gets stuck at "Verifying the unpacked files…". I get no error messages and when I give up and leave the page, there are no reports about a failed update. It just keeps showing me the "please update" message.
- I am using the default theme and want to change style.css. I cannot do this in the theme editor, it tells me I have to make the file writable first, even after I give all the theme files 777 access in my FTP client (which probably is not a good idea). If I edit the file offline instead and then upload it via FTP, this doesn't have any effect. I can even delete the entire file and still nothing changes at the frontend.
- I have tried to create a child theme through the FTP client but it does not show up in the WP backend.

The site is on a shared hosting platform. I can't find the details at the moment but it's a fairly regular setup (Linux, Apache, MySQL). I am testing in Firefox and caching is turned off. If I log out, and log back in again: same problems.

It is almost as if I am FTP-ing the wrong computer but I am really not. What am I missing?

Comment: Plz check the exact location of your theme folder from firebug. Inspect any element and check the location of your style.css

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that, Firebug tells me that style.css is in [my wp root]/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen and that is exactly where I tried to edit it through FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I finally asked my hosting provider and as it turns out they had adjusted a few settings, making them too restrictive.